# How to find word with part of surrounding context using grep?

Tags: command-line, grep

I want to use grep to determine how many characters should be displayed before and after what is being searched.
For example I want to filter 'example' from the 'this is an example' line.
By using `grep example` the result would be all the line containing the string, when what I hope to obtain is just "*an example*", two characters before the word *example*.

Comment: I have the impression that you want to stretch the possiblilities of `grep`. As Archemar indicates, it's indeed possible to do what you want solely using `grep`, but the best practice is to combine the strength of `grep` with the possibilities of `sed` (as indicated by Sartoris) or `awk`.

Comment: grep is perfectly capable of this. See Archemar's answer.

Comment: @Dominique Honestly, I can't see why you couldn't do `grep -o (\b\s){n}yourword` if you wanted to capture n words before yourword. I also can't see how additional processing is seed as "best practice".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

there are grep options

```
grep -Eo '...example' test.txt
```

where

- `-E` use extended regular expression
- `-o` ouput only matched string
- `...` means any 3 character
- both option can be merge as `-Eo`
- ' ' enclose patern to avoid shell subsitution

---

As sugested, alternative for 3 or less caracter

```
grep -Eo '.{,3}example' test.txt
```

where `x{a,b}` stand for between a and b occurence of x

- `.{,3}` up to 3 any char
- `X{2,10}` from 2 to 10 consecutive X (upper case X)
- `[xy]{5}` exactly 5 of either x or y

---

a note about shell substitution

```
grep -Eo ???example file
```

might not work as expected if a file like `123example` is present in dir where grep is being run.

Comment: Would it not be better to enclose the pattern in single quotes `'...example'` to avoid shell replacements? Not relevant in this case but sometimes very important.

Comment: Why use `-E` here? it doesn't seem necessary

Comment: @steeldriver Glance at man shows that there might be some difference between basic and extended regexp mode in non-GNU grep, so I would say - portability.

Comment: @TNW I would hope that `.` would be pretty portable...?

Comment: Note that this won't match if there are less than 3 characters on the same line before `example` (which may or may not be what the asker wants). One could use `'.?.?.?example'` as pattern to avoid this behavior (and print up to three previous characters).

Comment: @PhilippWendler  ... or `.{,3}` or something similar.

Comment: @Archemar: can you take the comment of @PhiippWendler in your response? It ist definitely the best answer: `grep -Eio '.{,40}example.{,40}'`

Answer (score 5):

You can pipe the output from grep to sed. Here's an example:

```
grep example test.txt | sed 's/.*\(...example\)/\1/'
```

For a sed tutorial, see http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html